# Unable to connect error Continuous Integration using TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, continuous-integration, webdeploy

I am trying to create a CI `Continuous Integration` to my project my project structure is as follow.

```
Solution
 |_ WebApi 1
 |_ WebApi 2
 |_ WebApi 3
 |_ Website "Single Page App"
```

I created a web deploy for each service to deploy it to server automatically each time i need to publish the application with the same name.

I created a batch script to run the publish so this is semi automatically approach.

I want to create a CI `Continuous Integration` so I create a new Build Definition to my project and add the following configuration

[image: General]

[image: Trigger]

[image: Source Setting]

[image: Build Definition]

[image: Process]

the following error appear to me 
[image: Error]

What i am missing in configuration of the Build Definition?

Comment: These are just missing dependencies. Have you inlcuded your packages in Source Control? You only want the NuGet repositories.config or the packages.configs otherwise NuGet will not get these packages as it thinks it already has them. Alternatively, have you enabled package restore in the solution properties?

Comment: I have enabled Nuget in solution and enable Nuget in tfs server by adding global environment variable "EnableNuGetPackageRestore" and set its value to true 

about including my packages to source control. i shouldn't include it to source control because i want nuget to make its role so i am letting nuget update the packages in deploying 

package.config included in each solution

Comment: Just to be clear. Your packages.config file is in source control but the actual packages themselves are not. Correct?

Comment: Yes, to make sure that Nuget do the effort of installing new packages each time so this is the problem as i think in CI

Comment: Did you try to trigger a manually build to see whether you would get the same error?

Comment: Yes, i have tried manual build and the same error happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error messages, the issue may be caused by Nuget packages not restored correctly.

You can follow steps in this blog to restore the packages: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build).

Some key steps are:

1. Add nuget.config and .tfignore file to the solution.
2. Add one build.proj file under the root path of the solution folder.
3. Create one folder named tools under the root path of the solution folder. Create NuGet sub-folder under tools folder, download and save nuget.exe under tools\NuGet path.
4. Check in nuget.config, .tfignore, build.proj and tools\NuGet\nuget.exe into TFS version control.
5. Modify the build definition to choose to build the build.proj file.
   Then you will have NuGet packages restored successfully during the TFS build process.

Comment: Thanks for your help in that but i am still have an issue the build running on `C:\Builds\5\ADSVC\HCMS - Continues Integration\src\build.proj` but folder `5` is not included in `Builds` folder i have only one folder called `1` when by chance the pass is `C:\Builds\1\ADSVC\HCMS - Continues Integration\src\build.proj` the build success

Comment: The number is supposed to mean the build agent, do you have multiple build agents? Are you using TFS 2013?

Comment: I don't have multiple build agents only one. and yes i am using TFS 2013 and in build agent properties i fond the following `$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)` I think the problem here is the `$(BuildAgentId)` is random should i make it static

Comment: Build Agent Working Directory $(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath) is correct, you shouldn't modify it. You may try to clean the cache files on your build agent machine to see whether the issue persists. C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache and C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\_tfs_data

Comment: its not working also, It works only one time then the same error happened